# Import SqlGeography datatypes using Copy activity in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to import a table in SQL server to ADLS Gen2, I have SqlGeography datatypes in one of the SQL Server tables. So, it is failing While using copy activity it is throwing below error. Can someone help me how to import SqlGeography to ADLS Gen2?

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=DataTypeNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column: Spatial,The data type Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography is not supported from the column named Spatial.,Source=,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy data1",
    "details": []
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is file type in ADLS where you are trying to copy

Answer (score 0):

When you copy data from SQL table to ADLS in particular file format some data types are not supported

- **CSV file** - If SQL input column in `SqlGeography` data type it will store the data by converting it into string.
- **JSON file** - If SQL input column in `SqlGeography` data type it will throw error it doesn't support the corresponding data type.
- **Parquet file** - If SQL input column in `SqlGeography` data type it will throw error it doesn't support this data type.

When coping the data from SQL to Parquet file I go the same as you it is because

> The complex data types (e.g. MAP, LIST, STRUCT) are currently supported only in Data Flows, not in Copy Activity.

To work around this, you can convert the `SqlGeography` data type to the `varchar` in source itself and then copy it in parquet file.

**Sample query:**

```sql
select col1, cast(col2 as varchar(max))as col2  from table-name
```

[image]

**Copied successfully:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! I get data to ADLS gen2 using control table, So, I use Table option here, do we have dynamic way to select Query option here?

Comment: No there is no dynamic way to switch between table and query format